# On moments of inertia of planar and 3D convex bodies

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, classical-mechanics

The following observation can be readily proved using the perpendicular axes theorem and intermediate value theorem: "Given any planar figure C, through any point on it, there is at least one pair of mutually perpendicular lines lying on the same plane such that the moments of inertia of C about the two lines are equal."

1. For a general planar convex figure C, what can one say about points on C with *more than one* such pair of mutually perpendicular lines? For example, is there only exactly one point with more than one pair of such mutually perpendicular lines through it (for a circular disk, its center obviously has infinitely many such line pairs)? Or is it that such a point can only be the center of symmetry if C is centrally symmetric?
2. Are there non-trivial variants of the above observation in 3D? For example, could one say: "for any convex 3D body C, there is at least one point P in it such that there is at least one set of 3 mutually perpendicular lines passing through P with moments of inertia of C about the 3 lines are equal."?

Aside: The perpendicular axes theorem (for that matter, even the parallel axes theorem!) seems to depend on the geometry being Euclidean. I don't know if it has an interesting variant in Hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Positive answer to question 2 follows from the recent answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435868/a-property-of-even-continuous-functions-on-the-sphere

Comment: Thanks very much Professor Eremenko for pointing this out