# On 'special' points on uniform planar convex regions defined in terms of moment of inertia

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

The following can be easily proved using perpendicular axes theorem and intermediate value theorem:

**Lemma:** Given any uniform planar convex region $C$ and any point on it, $P$, there will be at least one pair of mutually perpendicular lines that pass thru $P$ and lie on the same plane as $C$ such that the moment of inertia (MI) of $C$ about both lines are equal.

Symmetries in $C$ can lead to some points on $C$ being 'special' - such that w. r. to more than 2 lines thru them, MI of $C$ is the same; the center of a circular disk is obviously very special.

**Question:** Is it possible that for any planar convex $C$, there is at least one special point - a point with more than 2 lines passing through it giving the same MI for $C$? If such a special point always exists for any $C$, in the case when $C$ is a triangle, will it coincide with any known center of the triangle?

**Remark:** Above lemma won't hold for *other moments* - those defined with powers of distance from the axis different from quadratic. But analogous questions about concurrent lines yielding the same moment  for $C$ could be asked - maybe with special points having only 2 lines of same moment passing thru them.

**Note (January 2024):** This question does overlap with this earlier question: [On moments of inertia of planar and 3D convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435361/on-moments-of-inertia-of-planar-and-3d-convex-bodies;) but the bit on the possible triangle center seems new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\ep}{\delta}$The answer is as follows:

- Yes, if the special point is allowed to be not in $C$, and then the moments of inertia of $C$ about all lines through that special point will be the same.
- Not in general if the special point is required to be in $C$.

Indeed, the moment of inertia of $C$ about the line $l_{p,a}$ through a point $p=(p_1,p_2)$ orthogonal to a unit vector $a=(a_1,a_2)$ is
\begin{equation*}
    M(p,a):=\int_C(a\cdot(x-p))^2\,dx,
\end{equation*}
where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product. So,
\begin{equation*}
    M(p,a)=a\cdot G(p)a, \tag{-1}\label{-1}
\end{equation*}
where $G(p)$ is the $2\times2$ matrix with entries
\begin{equation*}
    G(p)_{i,j}=\int_C(x_i-p_i)(x_j-p_j)\,dx \\ 
    =\int_C x_i x_j\,dx+p_i p_j \int_C\,dx-p_i\int_C x_j\,dx-p_j\int_C x_i\,dx. \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
By shifting and rescaling, without loss of generality (wlog) $\int_C\,dx=1$ and $\int_C x_j\,dx=0$ for $j=1,2$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    G=H+p\otimes p,
\end{equation*}
where $H$ is the $2\times2$ matrix with entries $H_{ij}:=\int_C x_i x_j$ and $p\otimes p$ is the $2\times2$ matrix with entries $p_i p_j$.

The matrix $H$ is positive definite. So, by a rotation, wlog $H$ is a diagonal positive-definite matrix, so that
\begin{equation*}
    M(p,a)=\la_1 a_1^2+\la_2 a_2^2+(p_1 a_1+p_2 a_2)^2,
\end{equation*}
where $\la_1$ and $\la_2$ are real numbers such that, wlog, $\la_1\ge\la_2>0$.

Fix now a point $p$ and a unit vector $a$, and let
\begin{equation*}
    m:=M(p,a). 
\end{equation*}
Suppose now that the moment of inertia of $C$ about the line $l_{p,b}$ (through $p$ orthogonal to a unit vector $b=(b_1,b_2)$) is $m$ as as well. This means that $b$ is a solution to the system of equations
\begin{equation*}
    \la_1 b_1^2+\la_2 b_2^2+(p_1 b_1+p_2 b_2)^2=m,\quad b_1^2+b_2^2=1. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
Let us say that a unit vector $b$ is good and that the line $l_{p,b}$ is good if $b$ is a solution of system \eqref{1}. Given $p$, the good lines $l_{p,b}$ are in the one-to-one correspondence with the sets of the form $\{b,-b\}$, where $b$ is good. Say that unit vector $b$ and $-b$ are equivalent to each other.

The first equation in \eqref{1} is the equation of an ellipse centered at the origin and the second equation in \eqref{1} is the equation of the unit circle. So, we have either

- Case 1: the ellipse is the same as the circle, and then any line through $p$ is good or
- Case 2: the ellipse is not the same as the circle, and then we have at most two non-equivalent good unit vector $b$'s, and thus at most two good lines.

Clearly, Case 1 occurs only if $p_1 p_2=0$.
So, given the condition $\la_1\ge\la_2>0$, Case 1 occurs only if $p_1=0$ and $p_2^2=\la_1-\la_2$.

However, then both corresponding points $(p_1,p_2)=(0,\pm\sqrt{\la_1-\la_2})$ may be not in $C$. E.g., for small $\de\in(0,1)$, let $C=C^{(\de)}:=[-\frac1{2\de},\frac1{2\de}]\times[-\frac\de2,\frac\de2]$. Then $C$ is convex with the centroid at the origin and with area $1$, the matrix $H$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $\la_1=\frac1{12\ep^2}$ and $\la_2=\frac{\ep^2}{12}$, so that the points $(0,\pm\sqrt{\la_1-\la_2})=(0,\pm\sqrt{1/12}\sqrt{1-\ep^4}/\ep)=:p_\pm^{(\de)}$ are not in this $C=C^{(\de)}$ if $\de$ is small enough. $\quad\Box$

---

Below one can see the rectangle $C^{(\de)}$ and the points $p_\pm^{(\de)}$ for $\de=1/3$. Then the moments of inertia $M(p_\pm^{(\de)},a)$ about all the lines $l_{p_\pm^{(\de)},a}$ through the points $p_\pm^{(\de)}$ are equal to $\la_1=3/4$, for all (normal) unit vectors $a$.

[image]

---

It follows from \eqref{-1} and \eqref{0} that the moments of inertia $M(p,a)$ depend on $C$ only through the moments $\int_C\,dx$, $\int_C x\,dx$, $\int_C x\otimes x\,dx$ (of the mass distribution over $C$) of orders $0,1,2$. So, the condition of the convexity of $C$ plays hardly any role here.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that any point P on the plane of C has either 2 mutually perpendicular lines thru P for which C has equal moment of inertia or infinitely many lines thru P for which C has equal MI (no 'in between' points). in the special case when C is a triangle, there might be only one 'really special' point on the plane. If so, is this special point the same as any known center of the triangle? it appears: arguments above, including the lemma (holds for any point on the plane of C, not only in its interior) depend on the moment being MI and not any other moment.

Comment: @NandakumarR : I think that if, instead of the narrow rectangle, you take a narrow triangle, then the "really special" points will be outside the triangle, just as they are for narrow rectangles.

Comment: Thanks. Even the circumcenter, say, of a triangle could be outside so one suspects this 'really special' point (if unique) could be another center, maybe always coincident with some better known center.

Comment: @NandakumarR : I see your point. Will have this in mind.